# Problem with the block with the word wrap in algorithmicx

Tags: algorithmicx

For a good word wrap, I use this code in algorithmicx:

```
\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\algorithmicindent}{<text>\strut}
```

But when the code contains several nested structure leaves a block of code. How to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Examples}\label{alg:Examples}
  \begin{algorithmic}
  \While{$Y<5$}

  \If{$quality\ge 9$}
  \State \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\algorithmicindent}{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \strut}
  \EndIf

  \EndWhile
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[a busy cat http://harrix.org/2013-04-24_013858.png](http://harrix.org/2013-04-24_013858.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are inside a second block nesting level, you need two `-\algorithmicindent`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% just for the example 
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm} 

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Examples}\label{alg:Examples}
  \begin{algorithmic}
  \While{$Y<5$}

  \If{$quality\ge 9$}
  \State \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\algorithmicindent-\algorithmicindent\relax}{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \strut}
  \EndIf

  \EndWhile
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `showframe` just for visualization purposes.